# CodeSanbox seperate downloading option?

Tags: html, zip, codesandbox

I'm a freshman stuck with a school Chromebook that blocks extensions and apps, so CodeSandbox is my best option for a code editor.

I'm quite new to CodeSandbox, so I'm not completely sure how to download specific files. I have an HTML file in my Explorer along with the package.json, and I have the option to download both of the files as a .zip. But my Chromebook will not allow me to open and extract the zip file so I cannot access the HTML file I would like to open. So, is there I way that I can just download only the HTML file, as I cannot open the zip? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exporting to github. You could then copy/paste all the code from one file. I don't think that there is a way to download just one file.

Comment: I'm also unfamiliar with how exactly GitHub can be used to download files, would I need to create a new repository or project? And how can I place the code and download it as .html?

Comment: new respiratory. I'm not sure if you can download from just one file, but you can copy all the text in the file and paste it in a new place.

Comment: I've added the information from the HTML into the respiratory and created a new file for it, but how can I access and/or download that file?